# How to add vertical menu items in MS-Word ribbon using manifest.xml file in Word Add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I want to add menus buttons in vertical alignment in MS Word ribbon using manifest.xml. When i add button control they are aligned side by side horizontally, i want them to be align vertically instead, as the last column in provided image.

[image: Menu Image]

here is my manifest.xml

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">              
    <CustomTab id="wizdom.tab.name">
        <Group id="wizdom.Group1">
          <Label resid="wizdom.groupLabel" />  
          <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
          </Icon>

          <Control xsi:type="Button" id="wizdom.TaskpaneButton">
            <Label resid="wizdom.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
            <Supertip>    
              <Title resid="wizdom.TaskpaneButton.Label" />   
              <Description resid="wizdom.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="wizdom.icon_32x32" />
            </Icon> 

            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
              <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>      
              <SourceLocation resid="wizdom.Taskpane.Url" />
            </Action>
          </Control>                                               
        </Group>
    </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no way to customize the layout of a button group with Office Add-ins. To ensure a consistent experience, Office keeps control of the layout. If you shrink the Office window enough, you'll see the buttons shrink and their alignment change. For example, the following show the Script Lab add-in when Office is full screen and when it is resized much smaller. 
[image] [image]